# Angular JS + Java Servlet Route Issue

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, servlets

I have an application built using Angular JS.
It has 3 views say (A, B and C).
This is how I have configured the route params.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/',{
    controller:'aController',
    templateUrl: 'jsps/a.jsp'
})
.when('/b',{
    controller:'bController',
    templateUrl: 'jsps/b.jsp'
})
.when('/c',{
    controller:'cController',
    templateUrl: 'jsps/c.jsp'
})
.otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
```

});

All three views have **Login** Link. Clicking on LogIn will redirect the user to a different page within my application.

The Login is a form, which calls the LoginServlet and on successful authentication I am redirecting the user to my application.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
rd.include(request,response);
```

I also tried with rd.forward(request, response)

index.jsp is the default page which has ng-view.
So by default always view A is loaded after authentication.

Now my situation is when the user is requesting login from B or C, he has to be redirected to that view after authentication.

I have tried **request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp#/B");**
But this doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url fragment #/b is not sent to the server (Refer [Get anchor from URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637211/get-anchor-from-uri) for more details). If you need this information on server, you need to use query parameters. The solution would be (pseudocode)

- Embed this information as query parameter in the login link Eg: `<a href="/login?from=/b"></a>`
- Use hidden input field in the login form to hold the query parameter 'from'  `<input type="hidden" name="from" value="${param.from}">`Hence this will be available in to server when the login form is submitted.
- After login redirect the user `"index.jsp#" + request.getParameter("from")`