# How can I use a # symbol instead of ? in URLQueryItem?

Tags: swift, nsurlcomponents

If I create a URL like this:

```
    guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: "https://example.com/something", resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else {
        return
    }

    let queryItems = URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: token)
    urlComponents.queryItems = [queryItems]

    guard let urlWithQueryItem = urlComponents.url else {
        return
    }
```

I want the end result to be something like https://example.com/something#token=7as78f6asd678768asd768asd678

Instead of the default https://example.com/something?token=7as78f6asd678768asd768asd678

(I'm looking for something smarter than a search and replace of the ? character)

Thanks

Comment: Query items are always (per HTTP and URI specifications) separated by '?'.  # is used to introduce an anchor into link, but even then it's processed entirely locally and *not* part of the transmitted HTTP request.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637244/3203487.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, URLQueryItem object is more intended for use with querystrings vs anchors/fragments.  With that said, below is a function that helps you accomplish what your questions is asking.

```
func constructURL(withURL urlBase: String, andFragmentFromQueryItem queryItem: URLQueryItem) -> URL?{

guard let url = URL(string:urlBase) else {
    return nil
}

guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else {
    return nil
}

let fragmentKey = queryItem.name
let fragmentValue = queryItem.value ?? ""

urlComponents.fragment = "\(fragmentKey)=\(fragmentValue)"

guard let urlWithFragment = urlComponents.url else {
    return nil
}

return urlWithFragment

}

let url = constructURL(withURL:"https://example.com/something", 
andFragmentFromQueryItem: URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: "tokenValue"))
let urlString = url?.absoluteString 
print("\(urlString!)")
```

Here is a link to a working Swift fiddle of the code. 
http://play.swiftengine.io/code/8JKI3/2

Answer (score 1):

As @rmaddy points out, there is a definite difference between the meaning of ? and #.  '?' introduces query parameters, which are part of the URL.  '#' introduces the "fragment" which is *not* considered part of the URL.

You can, however use `URLComponents` to add a fragment to a URL.  Just use the `fragment` property instead:

```
urlComponents.fragment = "token=\(token)"
```