# How to route Url with # character in Asp.Net 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

How to route url contains # sharp character like this:
~/page.aspx#/Home
to be:
~/Home

Answer (score 4):

The `#` in a URL refers to a named anchor (`<a name="xxx" />`) tag and does not get passed through to the server.

`~/page.aspx#/Home` refers to the anchor named `/home` on the page `page.aspx`.

The server will only get the request to `page.aspx` and anything from the `#` onwards will not be passed through.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932184/how-do-i-get-url-label-when-parsing-request-url) SO question and answers.

In other words - do not use the `#` character in your URL if they do not refer to a named anchor within the document, as you will not be able to get these routed in the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think Oded has the right answer here.

But if you happen to have a situation where the # is in user entered data, you should URL escape it before putting it in the URL.

`#/Home` would then be `%23/Home`

However, I get the feeling this isn't actually the case here.