# How to get the anchor name in HTTP GET?

Tags: java, servlets

In a Java web project, how can I get (if possible) the "HTTP anchor" part in a URL request? 
For example, when the request URL is http://localhost:8080/servlet/page.htm?param1=value1&param2=value2#section I want to be able to recognize the `#section` part.

```
public void doGet
(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException 
{
  // ...
  System.out.println("QueryString = " + request.getQueryString());
  // ...
}
```

The example above produces the substring *preceeding* the `#`, in this case: `param1=value1&param2=value2`. Is there a way to extract the part of the URL *after* the `#` sign?

If this is of any use, I'm using the Apache Click framework.

Comment: looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932184/how-do-i-get-url-label-when-parsing-request-url

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think the anchor part is send to the server. It is only processed by the browser. Maybe you can extract it using JavaScript.

According to [RFC 1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt):

> Note that the fragment identifier (and the "#" that precedes it) is
>      not considered part of the URL.

From http://iwebdevel.com/2009/06/10/javascript-get-anchor-from-url/

```
var url=window.location;
var anchor=url.hash; //anchor with the # character  
var anchor2=url.hash.substring(1); //anchor without the # character
```

Comment: you're right, it's not sent to the server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637211/jsp-servlet-anchor/1637244#1637244