# In spring MVC, how to get full request URL including the fragment, like http://stackoverflow.com/myquestion#test=1234

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to know  how to get full request url 
I need #test=1234 but using HttpServletRequest request.getRequestURI() or request.getRequestURL().toString()
return path only, like https://stackoverflow.com/myquestion
Help me

Answer (score 5):

`#test=123` is called an Anchor. And Anchors are not submitted to the server, they only reside in the Broswer

@see:

- [How to get the anchor name in HTTP GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745993/how-to-get-the-anchor-name-in-http-get)
- [Retrieving Anchor Link In URL for ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Anchors or URL fragments are not sent by the client to the server when requesting for a resource. The anchor's or fragment's are utilized to identify a location within a resource and not a different resource on the server.

Fragment URL is not part of the URL. You can get the anchor using javascript & save them in cookies to retain them.

```
var anchor = window.location.hash;
```

Comment: Downvoter, Please let me know the reason. Read the accepted answer here & let me know  what was wrong in my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745993/how-to-get-the-anchor-name-in-http-get

Comment: Well I thought it was a perfectly valid answer. Back up to 0!