# How to set URI parameters in JSF managed bean?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, url-parameters, backing-beans

I know I can use the `<f:viewParam>` tag to set GET request parameters in a managed bean. This works great when passing URL as:

```
mysite.com/products.xhtml?catId=growing-systems
```

But is there another mechanism to process URI addresses such as:

```
mysite.com/products.html#/growing-systems -OR-
mysite.com/products.html#/growing-systems/garden-tower-3370084_01
```

Where the search strings (parameters for all intents and purposes) are separated by dashes.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Those aren't URL parameters, so you can't receive them as URL parameters. URL parameters are name-value pairs.

Comment: Dashes ("-") or *slashes* ("/")? [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) handles your apparent need precisely

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies. @kolossus, PrettyFaces looks awesome! It is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't accept as answer because this tip was given as a comment. Everyone else looking for this solution, this is the answer. Check out this comment explaining a basic configuration: `<!-- Maps "/user/#{username}" to the URL "/user/view.xhtml?username=value" -->`

Answer (score 0):

The anchor part of the URL is intercepted by the browser, and is not part of the URL POST/GET request back to the server. You might be able to locally process the URI with anchor within the browser using javascript.
See [previous answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6746016/744133) and [previous answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637244/744133)